# Why is this value null?

Tags: java, android, arrays, database, string

### I am succesfully making, saving, and retrieving my shared preferences from my `mainActivity`, but I cant get it from my service...

For some reason, my shared preferences is null when I try to retrieve it from a background service...

**I initialize my preferences in onCreate:**

```
contactsPrefs = getSharedPreferences("contactsPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE); //Making a shared preferences
```

**Save values in onCreate:**

```
    myEditor = contactsPrefs.edit();

    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    set.addAll(contactArrayList);

    myEditor.clear(); //Clearing current values in shared pref
    myEditor.putStringSet("contactSetKey", set); //Adding contacts
    myEditor.commit();
```

**All this is going fine, but when I try to access my preferences from my service, I get null:**

```
    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c); //See edit at bottom for more info
```

---

```
if(preferences.getStringSet("contactSetKey", null) != null) {
        contactArrayList.addAll(preferences.getStringSet("contactSetKey", null));

        for (String number : contactArrayList) {

            number.substring(number.indexOf("-") + 1); //Remove all characters before the hyphen from my string

            Log.v(TAG, number);

        }
    }else{
        Log.v(TAG, "Dagnabit it its null");
    }
```

And to my disappointment, I get the log `Dagnabit it its null`. why is it null? I can assure you that it works from my main activity, because I am able to display all of my data from my shared preferences when I access it from my shared preference. So I know that it shouldn't be null...But it is for some reason

Thanks,

Ruchir

### EDIT:

I actually register a volume listener using content observer, and I am accesing the preferences from there. Here is in the service:

```
 mSettingsContentObserver = new volumeCheck(this, new Handler());
        getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(android.provider.Settings.System.CONTENT_URI, true, mSettingsContentObserver);
```

Here is the Content Observer:

```
   public class volumeCheck extends ContentObserver {

 public volumeCheck(Context c, Handler handler) {
        super(handler); //Creates a new handler
        context = c; //variable context, defined earlier, is set equal to c, context of service.

        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);

}
```

Comment: i notice that in the last bit of code, the var `preferences` is used instead of `contactsPrefs`. Is that intentional?

Comment: @flkes Yeah, I have updated my question to show the instantiatetion of my preferences. :)

Comment: @flkes I use `preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
` in the service. Is that the problem?

Comment: Nah, not sure. I was Just wondering! This link might help though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950043/how-to-use-getsharedpreferences-in-android

Comment: Do you need to add the `MODE_PRIVATE` parameter?

Comment: @flkes Why, could I fix it if I changed that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get shared pref reference using application context as shown below:

```
contactsPrefs = 
          getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("contactsPrefs", 
          MODE_PRIVATE); //Making a shared preferences
```

Note:
If you still getting null, then get the shared preference from onStart() method of the service instead of doing it inside onCreate().

EDIT:
I tested and its working

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SharedPreferences preferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("Status","Success");
    editor.apply();

    getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, true,
            new VolumeCheck(this, new Handler()));
}
}



import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.ContentObserver;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;


public class VolumeCheck extends ContentObserver {
private final SharedPreferences preferences;

private Context context;

public VolumeCheck(Context c, Handler handler) {
    super(handler); //Creates a new handler
    context = c; //variable context, defined earlier, is set equal to c, context of service.

    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c.getApplicationContext());
    String status = preferences.getString("Status", "");
    if(!status.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
    {
        // got the value read from shared preference
        Log.i("Reading value", status);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please see my edit of my question, it is in a service in a listener. Is that okay?

Comment: The code should be like below   
      @Override
       public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        contactsPrefs =
                getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("contactsPrefs",
                        MODE_PRIVATE); //Making a shared preferences
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

Comment: Did you see my edit? It is actually in a content observer, so I get `Cannot resolve getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: Look at the bottom of my question

Comment: oh, you are passing a context reference to the content observer, you can use it to get the shared preference.

Comment: How? Can you show me? BTW: The context is passed in from the service, where I register the listener. It is in the bottom of my question. Please let me know how to do it?

Comment: Please check edited answer with the sample code which i tested and its working.

Comment: Awesome, it worked! For some reason though, my `number.substring(number.indexOf("-") + 1); //Remove all characters before the hyphen from my string` is not working. How can I remove everything before the `-`?

Comment: Okay, but why is the hyephen not removing